# ArgumentNullException was Unhandled in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

While debugging the following codes shows that `ArgumentNullException was Unhandled`.
please rectify it with a briefing

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myArry(6) As String
    myArry(0) = "You Can Win"
    myArry(1) = "Jaz"
    myArry(2) = "The Mong he sold his ferrari"
    myArry(3) = "Babu"
    myArry(4) = "The Alchemist"
    myArry(5) = "MT"

    For i As Integer = 0 To myArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        ListBoxBooks.Items.Add(myArry(i))

    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When you debug this, which object is `null`?  We can't "rectify it" for you, you need to put in at least *some* effort.

Comment: when i becomes myArray(5),after this it shows error whilr break point debugging

Answer (score 1):

The  problem is that you have initialized an array which contains 7 items but only 6 are initialized. Hence the last is `null`/`Nothing` which raises the exception in [`ListBoxBooks.Items.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx).

So you either have to loop only the first 6, initialize all or use `Dim myArry(5) As String` to get a `String()` with 6 strings.    You could also check if it's null even that seems to be pointless:

However, i would also use `Length` instead of `GetUpperBound`:

```
Dim myArry(5) As String
myArry(0) = "You Can Win"
myArry(1) = "Jaz"
myArry(2) = "The Mong he sold his ferrari"
myArry(3) = "Babu"
myArry(4) = "The Alchemist"
myArry(5) = "MT"
```

Now the following `If myArry(i) IsNot Nothing`-check is redundant, i show it anyway:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To myArry.Length - 1
    If myArry(i) IsNot Nothing Then
        ListBoxBooks.Items.Add(myArry(i))
    End If
Next
```

Note: you also have to use `myArry.Length - 1`, otherwise that would cause the next exception if you try to access an index that is not available(arrays are zero based).

Comment: @jaz: have you noticed that i've edited my answer meanwhile? There are several issues. The core issue is that you have to use `Dim myArry(5) As String` to get an array with Length=6.

Comment: @jaz: i have edited it again to show the complete working code. Note that the `If myArry(i) IsNot Nothing` is not needed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each item As String In myArry
      If item<>"" Then
       ListBoxBooks.Items.Add(item)
      End IF
    Next
```

Comment: This is not working For Each item As String In myArry
      ListBoxBooks.Items.Add(item)
    Next